# Handshake Failure After Client Hello

Tags: c++, mysql, ssl, openssl

I developed an app by C++ and OpenSSL to monitor MySQL packets. My app act as a proxy. In no SSL connection everything is OK but when I use SSL connection it face with "Handshake Failure" exactly after receiving Client Hello.

I developed a ssl server using openssl and make it blocking and wait at right time for accept ssl connection.

Wireshark screenshot

[image: Wireshark Screenshot]
Openssl Output:

> 140167999850080:error:1408A0C1:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_CLIENT_HELLO:no shared cipher:s3_srvr.c:1352:
>
> 140167999850080:error:1408A0C1:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_CLIENT_HELLO:no shared cipher:s3_srvr.c:1352:

---

**Edited:** This is a part of code that interact with client when it detect ssl connection option is On. After receiving login request packet this code will run.

```
void mysqlNegotiation(X509* cert, EVP_PKEY* key, int fd) {
    SSL_library_init();
    SSL_load_error_strings();
    OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();

    SSL_CTX* context = SSL_CTX_new(TLSv1_server_method());

    SSL_CTX_use_certificate(context, cert);
    SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey(context, key);
    SSL_CTX_check_private_key(context);

    SSL_CTX_set_ecdh_auto(context, 1);
    SSL_CTX_set_verify(context, SSL_VERIFY_PEER | SSL_VERIFY_FAIL_IF_NO_PEER_CERT, 0);
    SSL_CTX_set_verify_depth(context, 4);
    SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations(context, "ca-cert.pem", "/etc/mysql/");

    SSL* ssl = SSL_new(context);
    SSL_set_fd(ssl, fd);

    int r = SSL_accept(ssl);
    if (r != 1) {
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        int err_SSL_get_error = SSL_get_error(ssl, r);

        switch (err_SSL_get_error) {
            case SSL_ERROR_NONE:
                printf("%d", 0);
                break;
            case SSL_ERROR_SSL:
                printf("%d", 1);
                break;
            case SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ:
                printf("%d", 2);
                break;
            case SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE:
                printf("%d", 3);
                break;
            default:
                printf("%d", -1);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I doubt that this code is correct: `    SSL_CTX* context = = SSL_CTX_new(TLSv1_server_method());
`. It probably does not even compile. Please make an actually working example which can be used to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Did you have a look which ciphers are offered by the client? Maybe make a packet capture? For example if the client offers only DH ciphers this will fail because you don't set any DH (not ECDH) param.

Comment: Source code modified! Yes, both offer a same cipher list

Comment: How did you check which ciphers the server offers? How did you check for the client?

Comment: What type of certificate does your proxy use, and what are the lists of cipher suites enabled on both sides of the proxy? Also this forces clients to use a client certificate (IIRC): `SSL_VERIFY_FAIL_IF_NO_PEER_CERT`. Finally, have you had a look at [TLS Client](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/SSL/TLS_Client) on the OpenSSL wiki?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be several reasons for this error, which indicates, as stated, that the client and the server do not implement a common cipher that can be negotiated. Some of the reasons are:

1. TLS protocol level mismatch. You might've, for example, used `SSLv23_method` setting `SSL_OP_ALL|SSL_OP_NO_SSLv2|SSL_OP_NO_SSLv3|SSL_OP_NO_TLSv1|SSL_OP_NO_TLSv1_1` via `SSL_CTX_set_options()`, indicating support only for TLS 1.2 or higher, but the client does not support anything higher than TLS 1.1. This is just one example, a protocol mismatch can also occur in many other ways, too.
2. The SSL cipher list, configured via `SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list()`, does not include any ciphers supported by the peer.
3. The SSL context was not initialized with DH parameters, and as such does not support [forward secrecy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_secrecy) and the peer supports only ciphers that support forward secrecy.

There could be other reasons too. It is not possible to provide an authoritative answer without examining the configuration of both the client and the server. Since only you have the access to the client's and the server's code, it's up to you to figure it out. The only real answer here: find another server code that works with your client, and look at its code to figure out what it's doing differently from your code.

Comment: Both client and server use TLSv1 and also both use the same cipher list. I also initialized DH parameter but it goes on same way. One thing that confused me is why immediately after client hello and before any negotiation it occur?

Comment: This error message is returned due to a failed negotiation. There is no separate error message for the negotiation phase. "no shared cipher" means failed cipher negotiation.

Answer (score 1):

A common error is that your man in the middle app does not setup any certificates which means that no ciphers can be used which require authentication, i.e. probably all ciphers the client offers. This then leads to "no shared cipher" alert as response to the ClientHello.  Of course this is only speculation since the code of your man in the middle proxy is not known.

If this speculation is wrong I suggest that you provide more information, i.e. [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that others can actually see the details of your setup and maybe even reproduce your problem.

Comment: @Heil_Me: There is no error checking for setting certificate and private key so it may well be that these operations failed.

Comment: In original code error checking implemented, this code is just a simple code to shows what I've done in original code. I cant share original code exactly because of my job policy.

Comment: @Heil_Me: the code does not look bad if the client support ECDH key exchange or RSA key exchange (if the certificate is RSA). If the client only supports DH key exchange it will fail. Did you take look at what ciphers the client supports? Also, while sharing at least some code is nice it might be that due to stripping job related stuff the error vanishes too. So it would be better if you could share enough code to actually can be used to reproduce the problem and not only the parts which you think might be relevant.